# Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu on 128 GB SSD and 1TB HDD drive. What is the best partitioning choice?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-10, swap

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 but I am not sure how to partition my drives.

My SSD drive (where Windows 10 is on) has around 50 GB free space and my 1TB HDD has around 600 GB free space. This HDD already contains some other files. Also I have 8GB RAM.

I am doubting between different kind of partitions and even after a couple of hours of research I cannot decide what would be the best set-up. Here are my *current* options:

1. All SSD. I would partition 40GB on the SSD drive and go /(20GB), swap(8GB), /home(12GB) --  Does Windows have enough space?, Can I access my HDD drive files?, Do I even need the swap in this case?
2. All HDD. Since I have more than enough space, it would look something like /(50-60GB), swap(8GB), /home(50-60GB) -- What is the downside of this non-SSD installation (speed and computing power)?
3. A Combination of SSD and HDD. I would use 40 GB SSD for /(32GB)& swap(8GB). My files (which require no precious SSD space) would be partitioned on the HDD  /home(50-60GB). --
   Can I still access my other HDD drive files?
4. ... Any other suggestions?

Currently, my OS starts in a matter of seconds and the same for all of the applications. Although the 2nd option sounds preferable to me (I will never experience memory shortage), I don't know how much this will effect the speed and stuff...

As you might have expected, I am new to all of this so It's very possible I am making some rookie mistakes here. My apologies for that.

Comment: #4 [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/581906/344926)  Put  `/home` on the SSD as well and then symlink Documents, Music, videos to the HDD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot Win 10 + Ubuntu SSD+HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985906/)

Answer (score 0):

I would install ubuntu on the hard drive in that case, it would run just fine. loading times would be slightly longer. 
You can access windows partitions in linux but windows fast tartup might cause some problems there. If you experience any problems mounting windows partitions in linux [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/236807/how-to-mount-your-windows-10-or-8-system-drive-on-linux/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same configuration as you and since you have less amount of space on your SSD, I would probably recommend you to install Ubuntu on the HDD. I think around 60GB would be enough. So i think you should go with your second option.

The only drawback to not using the SSD will be speed of booting of the OS. Otherwise, it will run fine. Computing power depends on the processor. So, I don't think it will get affected.

Answer (score 0):

4)

Ubuntu and Windows OS both on the SSD.
Ubuntu's /home goes on the HDD.
Put Windows Documents, Downloads, Music, and Pictures on HDD (easy to move after changing location by right-click on each category in left hand window pane of Explorer, pick Properties, choose Location, change to D:\users\USERNAME\Categoryname )
Put Ubuntu [swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072336/can-i-change-location-of-swapfile), Windows [pagefile.sys](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-move-page-file-in-windows-10-to-another-disk/) and [swapfile.sys](https://www.howtogeek.com/225143/what-is-swapfile.sys-and-how-do-you-delete-it/) on HDD (easy to move).

Why? SSDs last longer than HDDs, but they fail with little if any notice. HDDs don't last as long, but they give warning symptoms well in advance.